# Which hydrate isomer of [Cr(H2O)6]Cl3 have lowest electrical conductivity

Tags: coordination-compounds

I found this question in my book and the answer that was given is $\ce{[Cr(H_2O)_4 Cl_2]Cl.2H_2O}$ but I think it should be 
$\ce{[Cr(H_2O)_5 Cl]Cl_2.H_2O}$ because in this case only one $\ce{H_2O}$ molecule is released.
Which one is correct and why?

Comment: So what if H2O is released? H2O is not what conducts current anyway.

Comment: If my edit is correct then I think OP is wrong, the increase in electrical conductivity here depends on the number of $\ce{Cl^-}$ ions that go into the solution when the hydrated complex is ionized, and not the $\ce{H_2O}$ because its already there in excess in the solution.

Comment: If possible do include the sources you cite as reference in future questions and answers. We would appreciate if you could also improve upon framing your question so that its easier for us to understand and help you better. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substance having the lowest electricity conductivity is the substance producing the lowest number of ions in solution. The substance $[Cr(H_2O)Cl_2]Cl$ produces $1$ cation charged $1+$ and $1$ anion charged $1 -$. This is the lowest possible number of ions with complexes made with Chromium(III, water and Chlorine.

With $[Cr(H_2O)_6]Cl_3$, the dissolution in water produces 1 cation (with the charge +3) and 3 anions with the charge -1. This makes many more ions in solution.

Comment: Why isn't  $[CrCl_3(H_2O)_3]⋅3H_2O$ the right answer? No ion would have been produced then and hence no conductivity...

Comment: Alas ! The substance $\ce{[CrCl_3(H_2O)3]·3H_2O}$ does not exist.